# drop down list have no items on adding new row in grid view through button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a Grid view containing 3 drop down lists and 3 text boxes  each and a button. my drop down lists are populating data from data base. When i click on the button to add new row after filling the initial row. it sets the first row values fine and adds a new row. **but the new row has no items in drop down lists this is my problem.** secondly when i click the button again for adding third row it even looses the value of first row filled and **same problem comes with first row that there are no items in drop down lists.**

```
     void SetInitialRow()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column4", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column5", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column6", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column4"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column5"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column6"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //dr = dt.NewRow();

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();


    }

     void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;

        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;





            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox and dropdown lists values



                    DropDownList list1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList list2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList list3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox3");


                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"] = list1.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"] = list2.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column3"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column4"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"] = list3.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column6"] = box3.Text;
                    Session["list1"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column1"];
                    Session["list2"] =  dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column2"];
                    Session["list3"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Column5"];

                    rowIndex++;


                }

                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();


            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks

        SetPreviousData();
    }
     void SetPreviousData()
    {

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {

            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    DropDownList list1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList list2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList list3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox3");
```

list1.DataSource = bindddl();

```
                     list1.DataValueField = "Item_name";
                     list1.DataTextField = "Item_name";
                     list1.DataBind();
                     list1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

                     list2.DataSource = binddd2();
                     list2.DataValueField = "Sub_item";
                     list2.DataTextField = "Sub_item";
                     list2.DataBind();
                     list2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

                     list3.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                     list3.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Yes", "1"));
                     list3.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("No", "2"));

                     box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                     box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                     box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();

                    list1.Text = Session["list1"].ToString();
                    list2.Text = Session["list2"].ToString();
                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();
                    list3.Text = Session["list3"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();
                  //  Response.Write(Session["list1"]);



                    rowIndex++;


                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();

            Fillcombo();
            Fillcombo1();
            Fillcombo2();

        }
```

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        AddNewRowToGrid();

        Fillcombo();
        Fillcombo1();
        Fillcombo2();


    }
```

Fillcombo,Fillcombo1 are functions which are populating Drop down lists 1,2 through data base Fillcombo2 is populating it has two items yes' and 'no'. 
My Fillcombo functions are like this

```
                try
        {
            string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdstr = new SqlCommand("SELECT    [Sub_item]  FROM [ADS].[dbo].[Accounts_heads_data]", conn);
                // SqlCommand cmdstr = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [ADS].[dbo].[Accounts_heads_data]  ", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr);


                DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();


                da2.Fill(ds2);

                DropDownList DropDownList2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[0].FindControl("DropDownList2");



                DropDownList2.DataValueField = ds2.Tables[0].Columns["Sub_item"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = ds2.Tables[0].Columns["Sub_item"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
                DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));

                ViewState["fc1"] = ds2;
                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need both text boxes and combo boxes? you can go ahead with only combo boxes. Your requirement is not clear

Comment: @voddy these are not combo boxes these are drop downlists. the methods are named as fill combo.i want dropdown list to populate itemsfrom Database on initial row they work fine. but on adding new row the new row doesnt contain items at all this is my problem

Comment: @voddy please reply and help

Comment: @voddy i have implemented your answer a new row is added on button click but the drop downs in new row arent containing data items :(

Comment: @voddy i have provided the code for Fill combo function as well see if thiss needs some editing

Comment: i did @voddy i made two functions that were returning me dataset than i gave my lists those functions as data source and finally i did that thanks by the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled your code with some test data and changed the code a bit. Try following and see.

```
   void AddNewRowToGrid()
    {
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    DropDownList list1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    DropDownList list2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList list3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column1"] = list1.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column2"] = list2.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column3"] = box1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column4"] = box2.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column5"] = list3.SelectedItem.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["Column6"] = box3.Text;
                }
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }
        SetPreviousData();
    }


void SetPreviousData()
{

    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {

        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                DropDownList list1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                DropDownList list2 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("DropDownList2");
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox1");
                TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox2");
                DropDownList list3 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("TextBox3");

                Fillcombo();
                Fillcombo1();
                Fillcombo2();


                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column4"].ToString();                    
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column6"].ToString();

                    if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                    {
                        list1.ClearSelection();
                        list1.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                        list2.ClearSelection();
                        list2.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString()).Selected = true;

                        list3.ClearSelection();
                        list3.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["Column5"].ToString()).Selected = true;
                    }

                rowIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
 }

  protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        AddNewRowToGrid();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

check by comenting 
SetPreviousData(); line from
AddNewRowToGrid function

OR

in AddNewRowToGrid function only set data for new row and call SetPreviousData(); function in first row of AddNewRowToGrid function.

Comment: the problem remains the same :(